# Firebase - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a problem, when there is little data in Firebase it works great.
But when I added a lot of data (not very much), it had loading problems and couldn't display the data.
I opened the console to see what errors there were and I got these:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=gEj-BqgbTh4aV_oeJcC9WJk8W5CG4GO-MP-T7wEjx0Y&VER=8&database=***%2F***-1c5da%2Fdatabases%2F(default )&RID=rpc&SID=***vm08bUxCCrD37d0g&AID=64&CI=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=***702exk8t3&t=3
```

Firebase Issue

[image]

What can I do to fix the data loading problem?

Thanks

I try to fix it but i didnt fint solution

This is the

```js
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Button, CategoriesView, Input, Label, Layout, ListFooter } from '../../components'
import En from '../../data/locals/En'
import { hp, commonStyles, wp, COLOR } from '../../data/StyleGuides'
import { IMAGES } from '../../assets/images'
import { FIREBASE_COLLECTION, SCREEN } from '../../data/enums'
import { useDoubleSearch, usePagination, useSearch } from '../../utils/hooks'
import { deleteDocument, getCollectionData } from '../../services/firebaseServices'
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { textLimit } from '../../utils/Helper'

const CategoryContentScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const documentId = route?.params?.id
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [subContent, setSubContent] = useState([])
    // const [subContentData, { search, handleSearch }] = useDoubleSearch(subContent, 'studyName', 'studyName')
    const [subContentData, { search, handleSearch }] = useSearch(subContent, 'studyName')
    const isFocused = useIsFocused()
    const {
        renderData,
        currentPage,
        moveToNextPage,
        moveToPreviousPage,
        showPreviousButton,
        showNextButton,
        noteString,
    } = usePagination(subContentData)
    useEffect(() => {
        getSubCategoriesData()
    }, [isFocused])
    const getSubCategoriesData = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        const data = await getCollectionData(FIREBASE_COLLECTION.CATEGORY_CONTENT)
        const selectedDocuments = data.filter(x => x?.parentId == documentId)
        setSubContent(selectedDocuments)
        setLoading(false)
    }
    const getSerialNumber = (index) => {
        const entriesPerPage = 5
        return (currentPage - 1) * entriesPerPage + index + 1
    }
    const handleDeleteItem = (id) => {
        deleteDocument(FIREBASE_COLLECTION.CATEGORY_CONTENT, id)
        getSubCategoriesData()
    }
    return (
        <Layout title={En.subCategoriesContent}>
            <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
                <Button
                    style={styles.buttonStyle}
                    text={En.addNewContent}
                    icon={IMAGES.AddIcon}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate(SCREEN.ADD_CATEGORIES_NOTE, { parentId: documentId })}
                />
                <View style={commonStyles.horizontalView}>
                    <Input
                        value={search}
                        onChange={handleSearch}
                        style={styles.inputContainer}
                    />
                    <Label style={{ fontWeight: '700' }}>{En.lookFor}</Label>
                </View>
            </View>
            <ScrollView
                bounces={false}
                overScrollMode='never'
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Label style={{ fontWeight: '700' }}>{En.operations}</Label>
                    <Label style={{ fontWeight: '700' }}>{En.subCategoryName}</Label>
                    <Label style={{ fontWeight: '700' }}>.{En.serialNumber}</Label>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.categorView}>
                    {loading ? <ActivityIndicator size={35} color={COLOR.red} style={{ marginTop: hp(2) }} />
                        :
                        renderData?.map((item, index) => (
                            <CategoriesView
                                text={item?.studyName}
                                key={index}
                                number={getSerialNumber(index)}
                                firstHeading={En.edit}
                                secondHeading={En.delete}
                                onFirstPress={() => navigation.navigate(SCREEN.ADD_CATEGORIES_NOTE, { isEdit: true, parentId: documentId, data: item })}
                                onSecondPress={() => handleDeleteItem(item?.documentId)}
                            />
                        ))}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <ListFooter
                note={noteString}
                showPreviousButton={showPreviousButton}
                moveToNextPage={moveToNextPage}
                moveToPreviousPage={moveToPreviousPage}
                currentPage={currentPage}
                showNextButton={showNextButton}
            />
        </Layout>
    )
}
export default CategoryContentScreen
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputContainer: {
        width: wp('10%'),
        borderRadius: hp(1),
        marginHorizontal: '1%',
        height: hp(5.7),
    },
    headerStyle: {
        ...commonStyles.justifyView,
        paddingHorizontal: '5%',
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        width: wp(20),
        ...commonStyles.center,
        height: hp(5)
    },
    container: {
        height: hp(6),
        width: '90%',
        marginHorizontal: '5%',
        backgroundColor: COLOR.secondary,
        borderRadius: hp(4),
        paddingHorizontal: '3%',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: '0.5%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical: '1%',
    },
})
```

And this is the firebaseServices.js

```js
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { addDoc, collection, getDocs, getDoc, doc, updateDoc, setDoc, where, deleteDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage'
import { FIREBASE_AUTH, STORAGE_CONFIG, FIRESTORE_DB } from '../../firebaseConfig'
import En from '../data/locals/En'

const loginWithEmail = async (email, password, callBack) => {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(FIREBASE_AUTH, email, password)
    .then(async data => {
      callBack(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      callBack()
      if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-credential') {
        alert(En.invalidCredentials)
      }
    })
}

const getCollectionData = async table => {
  let data = []

  let querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, table))
  querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      data.push({ ...doc.data() })
    } else {
      console.log('No document found!')
    }
  })
  return data
}

const getCollectionDataWhere = async (table, key, value) => {
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, table), where(key, '==', value))

    if (querySnapshot?.empty) {
      console.log('No documents found with', key, '=', value)
      return null
    }

    const data = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      data.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
    })

    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching document:', error)
    return null
  }
}

const getDocumentById = async (collectionName, documentId) => {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(FIRESTORE_DB, collectionName, documentId)
    const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef)

    if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
      return { id: docSnapshot?.id, ...docSnapshot?.data() }
    } else {
      console.log('No document found with ID:', documentId)
      return null
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching document:', error)
    return null
  }
}

const addDocument = async (coll, jsonObject) => {
  try {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(FIRESTORE_DB, coll), {
      ...jsonObject,
      documentId: null,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    })

    const documentId = docRef.id
    await updateDoc(docRef, { documentId })
    console.log('Document written with ID: ', documentId)
    return documentId
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error adding document: ', e)
    return null
  }
}

const deleteDocument = async (coll, documentId) => {
  try {
    return await deleteDoc(doc(FIRESTORE_DB, coll, documentId))
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error adding document: ', e)
    return null
  }
}

const saveData = async (coll, documentId, jsonObject) => {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(FIRESTORE_DB, coll, documentId)
    await setDoc(docRef, { ...jsonObject, capital: true, updatedAt: serverTimestamp(), }, { merge: true })
    return docRef.id
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error adding document: ', e)
    return null
  }
}

const uploadImage = async (imageUri, folder) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(imageUri)
    const blobFile = await response.blob()

    const storageRef = ref(STORAGE_CONFIG, `${folder}/` + new Date().toISOString())

    const result = await uploadBytes(storageRef, blobFile)
    const url = await getDownloadURL(result.ref)

    return url
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading image:', err)
    throw err
  }
}

export { addDocument, loginWithEmail, uploadImage, getCollectionDataWhere, getDocumentById, getCollectionData, saveData, deleteDocument }
```

Comment: Could you please add some code snippets related to the issue

Comment: ill add code...

Comment: Where to you call the connection to firebase from your application

Comment: you mean FirebaseConfig.ts File ? See what i add.

Comment: Did you check it ?